# How can I change the color of the text of a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to click a button and change its text's color and message properties.

I got the button to change its color, but I need to change one of its text's colors.

```
private void TurnGreen(Button button)
{
    ColorBlock colors = button.colors;
    colors.normalColor = Color.green;
    button.colors = colors;
}
```

The above code changed the button's color which I liked, but I would rather change the button's text. Note however that my button has two text-childs. The text I want to change has a name of "Ore".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't done Unity for ages, so my knowledge is bit rusty. 
Make sure `using System.Linq;` is set in your script.

```
        // Considering that "button" is the one on which you clicked.
        // By definition, we have 2 Text children (for single Text, we 
        // could use button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color directly, as it returns single element.
        var oreText = button.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "Ore"); // Unity allows same naming...
        // I had 2 Text components initially returned: Ore and Wood. 
        // Got the Ore text component with FirstOrDefault. Now check it really exists and set color.            
        if (oreText != null) // Long way to compare. For illustration.
        {
            oreText.color = Color.green;
        }
        // Also, if "Ore" button really exists, you can directly set it from "Single" method:
        // button.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>().Single(o => o.name == "Ore").color = Color.green;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this might be to identify the text component in question from the editor (assuming your button is a Prefab), rather than iterating through the components via Linq. If you do it that way, it's scales a little better if you want to use that type of behavior on other components/buttons but don't want to have to change the Linq search text each time.

To do this, create a new field like this:

```
public Text textToChange;
```

Then drag the component in question form your button into your component script from the editor, then in code do this:

```
textToChange?.color = Color.green;
```

And then boom, you're done...the '?.' also checks for null for you without the if block.

Comment: The button is not a prefab.

Comment: Is it instantiated at run-time? Even if it's not a prefab and you have it in your scene somewhere, this would still work and be more extensible.